# Error installing FBPROPHET in my windows machine

Tags: python, pip, time-series, facebook-prophet

I am getting the below mentioned error while installing `fbprophet` in the Windows environment, and, also setup.py is being triggered as part of installation as the installation using wheel file fails.

Installation of fbprophet library:
**Using legacy 'setup.py install' for fbprophet, since package 'wheel' is not installed**

```
(new_venv) C:\Users\anno_user\Downloads\DocumentDB-Quickstart-Python>pip install fbprophet
Collecting fbprophet
  Using cached fbprophet-0.7.1.tar.gz (64 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done

Using legacy 'setup.py install' for fbprophet, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: fbprophet
  Running setup.py install for fbprophet ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

And we are getting this following error when setup.py is installing the package:

```
  × Running setup.py install for fbprophet did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [45 lines of output]
      running install
      c:\users\anno_user\downloads\documentdb-quickstart-python\new_venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: se
tup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
      running build
      running build_py
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\anno_user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvgs_7ri\fbprophet_7865d66523254cabae59b7777322c65d\setup.py", line 149, in <module>
          long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
        File "C:\Users\anno_user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvgs_7ri\fbprophet_7865d66523254cabae59b7777322c65d\fbprophet\models.py", line 209, in build_
model
          import pystan
        File "c:\users\anno_user\downloads\documentdb-quickstart-python\new_venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
          from pystan.api import stanc, stan
        File "c:\users\anno_user\downloads\documentdb-quickstart-python\new_venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\api.py", line 13, in <module>
          import pystan._api  # stanc wrapper
      ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> fbprophet

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Please kindly suggest if there is any workaround (or) fix for the issue I am facing. Also, mention the python version along with the dependencies version for installing `fbprophet` from pypi.org.

Comment: As far as I remember, you need Anaconda as it has a separate build system with its own C++ compiler. Using Anaconda should help.

Comment: @annabednarsha, I feel so too, we are looking to install anaconda in a Linux environment to get around this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These commands no longer work.

a) "fbprophet" is now "prophet"

b) need legacy versions of pystan and cmdstanpy

pystan=2.19.1.1
cmdstanpy=0.9.5

My Windows OS fails to install pystan=2.19.1.1 so I have given up. But "pip install prophet" works on both Google Collab and GCP Workbench.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31809433)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using python 3.7 or 3.8

Answer (score 1):

I also had issues with fbprophet in python=3.9. The reason is it required pystan and that requires c++ compiler. So, it was not working in both Vscode or anaconda.

Since it is upgraded to prophet,it is working fine now.

```
!pip install prophet
from prophet import Prophet
```

Assuming you have a pandas dataframe df with a datetime column named "ds" and a target column named "y", then:

```
model = Prophet()
model.fit(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install Anaconda on Windows following [this instruction](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/) and then run the following in Anaconda Prompt (as administrator):

```
conda install -c conda-forge gcc
conda install -c conda-forge pystan
conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for this is to install 'prophet' module instead of 'fbprophet'
and while importing import 'prophet' instead of 'fbprophet'
so

```
python3 -m  pip install pystan
python3 -m  pip install prophet
```

or simply

```
pip install pystan
pip install prophet
```